# Getting a row in bootstrap to fadeout with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working pretty hard with making a todo list to the point where I have items on the list forming a table with Javascript. So far so good, but now I would like the items to fade out of the table with javascript. I found a pretty helpful site that gives some [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/od3n/j24e6ggw/) but I'm still stuck with implementing it the right way.

```
<tr>
  <td>aaa</td>    
  <td>aaa</td>      
  <td>aaa</td>
  <td class='deleterow'><div class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></div></td>
</tr>
```

and...

```
$(".deleterow").on("click", function(){
var $killrow = $(this).parent('tr');
    $killrow.addClass("danger");
$killrow.fadeOut(2000, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});});
```

is what I found on the site.

I'm basically trying to give the td class the delete row behavior in a destroy action in a destroy.js.erb file. I tried putting it in directly with what little java script I know, but it isn't working.

in my _item.html.erb file

```
<%=div_for item do%>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><%= item.name %></td>
            <td><%= "#{item.days_left}" %></td>
            <td class='deleterow'><%= link_to raw('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>'), [current_user, item], method: :delete, remote: true %></td>
        </tr>
```

in my destroy.js.erb file

```
$('.deleterow').on("click", function()
{
var $killrow = $(this).parent('tr');
    $killrow.addClass('danger');
$killrow.fadeOut(2000, function(){
    $(this).remove();
});});
Messenger().post({
    message: '<%= flash[:notice] %>',
})
```

Can anyone help out?